# Android EditText value looses ListView scroll up/down

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, default-value

this is my adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.txtid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3id);
        holder.txtThird = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
        holder.btn1 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.btn2 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!holder.txtThird.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Sayac = Integer.valueOf(holder.txtThird.getText().toString());
            } else {
                Sayac = 0;
            }
            Sayac++;
            holder.txtThird.setText(String.valueOf(Sayac));
        }
    });
    holder.btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!holder.txtThird.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Sayac = Integer.valueOf(holder.txtThird.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Sayac = 0;
            }
            if (Sayac > 0) {
                Sayac--;
                holder.txtThird.setText(String.valueOf(Sayac)); 
            }
        }
    });



    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    HashMap map = list.get(position);
    String first = (String) map.get(Seri);
    String second = (String) map.get(Sira);
    String id = (String) map.get(Tarih);

    holder.txtFirst.setText(first);
    holder.txtSecond.setText(second);
    holder.txtid.setText(id);
    holder.txtThird.setText("0");
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Here I insert into database table when amount is not equal to '0':

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lv.getAdapter().getCount()-1; i++) {
            HashMap<?, ?> result = (HashMap<?, ?>)lv.getItemAtPosition(i);       
            View vListSortOrder;
            vListSortOrder=lv.getChildAt(i);    
            TextView Sort_DeliveryOrder=(TextView)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
            String Fiyats = String.valueOf(result.get(Sira).toString().trim().replace(",", "."));
            String iskDizi[] = new String[3];
            if (Integer.valueOf(Sort_DeliveryOrder.getText().toString()) != 0) {
                //Process
            }
```

But I have a problem. ListView scroll up/down amount value gets default value on change. I need the ListView scroll up/down amount value **not to change** and not to set default value.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You talk about a 'listview' and 'amount value' but none of this is mentioned in the code. Also, please include *only* the code that is relevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you scroll views are recycle or new view are created, getView() method is called there you have set

```
holder.txtThird.setText("0");
```

rather you get saved data form database and set the text

```
int value = database.getValue();
holder.txtThird.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

see if this works :)